# In MAUI Blazor (Hybrid), how do I intentionally crash the app with an exception?

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui, maui-blazor

I want to test Firebase Crashlytics. I can test recording non-fatal crash using `RecordException` but I want to know the behavior when it actually crashes. However when I intentionally throw an exception, Blazor/the WebView handles it instead. I even tried to run it on the MainThread:

```cs
#if ANDROID
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This is an error");
        });
#endif
```

Still somehow the `ErrorBoundary` is still able to catch it.

How do I throw an exception that should crash a MAUI Hybrid app? In both Android and iOS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way for Android is to simply put it in the `MainActivity`. Unfortunately I do not know the equivalent code for iOS but I guess I can also put the code in `MainPage.xaml` as well:

```cs
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        await Task.Delay(5000);
        throw new Exception("This is intentional");
    }

}
```

The crash was successfully reported.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `1/0` you will get crash. The exception name 1 divide by zero. **Firebase Crashlytics** will take time but u will get crash on it very simple.

Comment: The WebView (Blazor) would handle that exception and so it would be non-fatal.